# Why does create next app install with postcss errors

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-dom, npx

The code in question is very simple. I have an "app" folder with a server directory inside. I open a terminal. I cd into app. I then type npx create-next-app client. next installs. I change directory to app/client. I run npm run dev.
I get this in console...

Error: Your custom PostCSS configuration must export a `plugins` key.

I tried with earlier version of create-next-app. Same. Tried with other installation on my machine. Same.

Is there any way to find out what postcss next thinks is being used?

Can i add a config to fix it?

Comment: No. I just cd into the folder. I'm guessing maybe I have tailwind installed globally?? I cant figure it out.

Comment: So yes I did. Just started my coffee. I edited the question to reflect that. thanks.

Comment: Do you have a custom PostCSS config file at all? What does it look like?

Comment: I didn't add anything to the create next app. That's why I'm at a loss. But, I'm getting the same error when I try to run another installation that previously worked. That one also has no exogenous post css configs.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer! I added a practically empty `postcss.config.json`.

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    
   
  ]
}
```

First, I tried using the exact example, "default", from the nextjs docs...

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
    [
      "postcss-preset-env",
      {
        "autoprefixer": {
          "flexbox": "no-2009"
        },
        "stage": 3,
        "features": {
          "custom-properties": false
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

That didn't work. Then I erased the json data leaving just an empty plugins array. Worked.

But why...

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to remove everything in the array, this Github issue thread mentions a fix for the bug https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/8884.

You need to remove the `require` call and pass the string instead:

```
plugins: [
    'autoprefixer' //instead of require('autoprefixer')
]
```